# how to change terimal start given character

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, linux-mint

i used a ubuntu variant mint,and it modfiy the terminal,each time i start a terminal,it given characters like belows:

```
 ________________________________________
( You will always have good luck in your )
( personal affairs.                      )
 ----------------------------------------
  o
   o
       ___  
     {~._.~}
      ( Y )
     ()~*~()   
     (_)-(_)
```

how to remove this,it take 1/3 space of my terminal,and boring,any one could give me a hand

Answer (score 4):

Linux Mint is configured to by default run the /usr/games/fortune command when opening a terminal. To stop this from happening, edit `/etc/bash.bashrc`. You will need superuser permissions to do this. At the end of the file, there is a line which reads:

```
/usr/games/fortune
```

simply delete this line.

Comment: or comment it out